# How to get flowlayout of collectionview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a `UICollectionViewController` in the storyboard. But I need to acccess to flowlayout... How do I access and use the flowlayout? **Here is my controller:**
Using collectionView.flowlayout did not work.

```
class TableCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var json: JSON?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cellWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/(CGFloat(json!["Rows"][0]["Column"].count)+1)

        return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, 100)
    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return json!["Rows"].count
        //return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return json!["Rows"][section]["Column"].count
        //return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        cell.label.text = json!["Rows"][indexPath.section]["Column"][indexPath.row].stringValue
        cell.label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        cell.label.numberOfLines = 0
        //cell.label.text = "deneme"

        // Configure the cell

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

it is `collectionView.collectionViewLayout` but you need to cast it as flow layout

Comment: You can cast it like this:
```guard let layout = yourCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }```

Answer (score 16):

You use the same `collectionViewLayout` variable, the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class you need is a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`:

```
if let collectionViewFlowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    // Use collectionViewFlowLayout

}
```

Answer (score 4):

while the above answers are valid for code generated collection views, there's also another way if you have yours generated via Interface Builder.

First, create an outlet for your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
```

Then assign it in Interface Builder:

[image]

And then use it with:

```
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```